# Using jquery tablesorter plug-in, have a drop down box with an item selected

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I have created a table that allows a user to edit/correct the data.  The table populates fine, and in order to make this table as easy to use as possible. I have added drop down boxes that they can select from when they need to change any information.

JS file is:

```
for(y=0;y<data.defect2.length; y++) {
    myselectoptions += '<option value="'+data.defect_id[y]+'"' +
        (data.defect_id[y]==data.defect[y] ? ' selected="selected"' : '') + 
        '>'+data.defect2[y]+'</option>';
}

if (data.isbn2 === null) {
    $("#inventoryUpdate").append('<tr><td>No Records Found</td></tr>');
} else {
    for(var x=0;x<data.isbn2.length;x++) {
        $("#inventoryUpdate").append('<tr><td id="tableSKU">'+data.sku[x]+'</td><td id="tableISBN">'+data.isbn2[x]+
        '</td><td id="tableQuantity">'+data.quantity[x]+
        '</td><td><select id="tableDefect">'+myselectoptions+//'" selected="'+data.defect[x]+'">'+myselectoptions2+
        '"</select></td><td><select id="tableSource">'+sourceoptions+
        '"</select></td><td><select id="tableFeature">'+featureoptions+
        '"</select></td><td><select id="tableWater">'+wateroptions+
        '"</select></td><td><select id="tableLocation">'+locationoptions+
        '"</select></td><td><input type="text" id="tableProcessDate" value="'+data.processDate[x]+
        '"/></td><td><select id="tableBookType">'+bookoptions+
        '"</select></td><td><select id="tableCreatedBy">'+useroptions+
        '"</select></td><td><select id="tableModifiedBy">'+useroptions+
        '"</select></td></tr>');
    }

    $("#inventoryUpdate").trigger("update");
}
```

This all works, except that I can't have it default to the selected item from the database query.  The item that is selected is the value of the very last item in the table.
Any ideas on how to accomplish this or is it impossible to do?

Comment: Are you sure that a default is being set in your first `for` loop? Have you verified in your output?

Comment: Yes, the drop down list is populated, I now need to have the value from the database set as the selected value.

Comment: No, I'm asking specifically if the default value your are trying to set in the `for` loop is being performed correctly. When you look at the output afterwards, do you see `<option>` tags with the `selected="selected"` attribute present?

Comment: no there is no selected attribute that is selected.

Comment: Okay, well, if I'm reading your code correctly then you should review your `for` loop code. That should be setting at least one default value.  Otherwise, no matter what you do, you won't get default values to show.

Comment: The first for loop creates the items in the drop down list and the second one puts it in the table.  I believe that this is where I need to put the selected, but i am not having any luck at this point.  I am willing to look at any and all options to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it took some doing but I finally figured it out.  I needed to put the

```
for(y=0;y<data.defect2.length; y++) {
     myselectoptions += '<option value="'+data.defect_id[y]+'"' +
         (data.defect_id[y]==data.defect[x] ? ' selected="selected"' : '') + '>'+data.defect2[y]+'</option>';
}
```

inside of the

```
if(data.isbn2 === null){
    $("#inventoryUpdate").append('<tr><td>No Records Found</td></tr>');
} else {
    for(var x=0;x<data.isbn2.length;x++) {
        $("#inventoryUpdate").append('<tr><td id="tableSKU">'+data.sku[x]+'</td><td id="tableISBN">'+data.isbn2[x]+
            '</td><td id="tableQuantity">'+data.quantity[x]+
            '</td><td><select id="tableDefect">'+myselectoptions+//'" selected="'+data.defect[x]+'">'+myselectoptions2+
            '"</select></td><td><select id="tableSource">'+sourceoptions+
            '"</select></td><td><select id="tableFeature">'+featureoptions+
            '"</select></td><td><select id="tableWater">'+wateroptions+
            '"</select></td><td><select id="tableLocation">'+locationoptions+
            '"</select></td><td><input type="text" id="tableProcessDate" value="'+data.processDate[x]+
            '"/></td><td><select id="tableBookType">'+bookoptions+
            '"</select></td><td><select id="tableCreatedBy">'+useroptions+
            '"</select></td><td><select id="tableModifiedBy">'+useroptions+
            '"</select></td></tr>');
    }
}
```

so the final product looks like this:

```
if(data.isbn2 === null){
    $("#inventoryUpdate").append('<tr><td>No Records Found</td></tr>');
} else {
    for(var x=0;x<data.isbn2.length;x++) { 
        for(y=0;y<data.defect2.length; y++) {
            myselectoptions += '<option value="'+data.defect_id[y]+'"' +
                (data.defect_id[y]==data.defect[x] ? ' selected="selected"' : '') +
                '>'+data.defect2[y]+'</option>';
        } 

        $("#inventoryUpdate").append('<tr><td id="tableSKU">'+data.sku[x]+'</td><td id="tableISBN">'+data.isbn2[x]+
            '</td><td id="tableQuantity">'+data.quantity[x]+
            '</td><td><select id="tableDefect">'+myselectoptions+//'" selected="'+data.defect[x]+'">'+myselectoptions2+
            '"</select></td><td><select id="tableSource">'+sourceoptions+
            '"</select></td><td><select id="tableFeature">'+featureoptions+
            '"</select></td><td><select id="tableWater">'+wateroptions+
            '"</select></td><td><select id="tableLocation">'+locationoptions+
            '"</select></td><td><input type="text" id="tableProcessDate" value="'+data.processDate[x]+
            '"/></td><td><select id="tableBookType">'+bookoptions+
            '"</select></td><td><select id="tableCreatedBy">'+useroptions+
            '"</select></td><td><select id="tableModifiedBy">'+useroptions+
            '"</select></td></tr>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than attempting to add the `selected` attribute during the initial rendering, I would suggest running it after. Something like this:

```
var selectedValue = 'option[value="'+data.defect_id[y]+'"]';
$('#tableDefect').find(selectedValue).attr("selected",true).end();
```

Comment: Based on my current code, how would I then put this into the table?

Comment: within your success function, but after the append.

Comment: I put that line right before my .trigger("update") and it defaults to the first item in the dropdown list.

Comment: i just realized, I think I should change the data.defect_id[y] in the selectedValue to just data.defect[x] since the selected item from the database is called defect.  Does that sound right to you?

Comment: Ok, so I have tried this every which way I can think of and it still does not work.  Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the value using code similar to following:

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/fwsyL/

**HTML**

```
<select id="Options">
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="3">Value 3</option>
    <option value="4">Value 4</option>
    <option value="5">Value 5</option>
</select>
<br />
<input id="TextSet" type="text" value="" style="width:50px;"/> 
<input id="ButtonSet" type="button" value="Set" style="width:50px;"/>​
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#ButtonSet').click(function() {
    $('#Options option[value="' + $('#TextSet').val() + '"]').attr("selected",true).end();
});
```

This is just another way for you to possibly work a solution out. Once I get more info. from you I can provide an answer specific to your code.
​